# .net 6 Attribute routes returning 404

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core

I asked a similar question a few days ago, but I've got an issue with another controller now and for the life of me I can't figure out why this is returning a 404.

API Controller...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FilesController
{
    private readonly IFilesService _filesService;

    public FilesController(IFilesService filesService)
    {
        _filesService = filesService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<SupportFile> GetFiles(int id) {
        return _filesService.GetFiles(id);
    }

    [HttpGet("DownloadFile/{fileName}")]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {

        return await _filesService.DownloadFile(fileName);
    }
}
```

Program.cs...

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DapperContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISupportService, SupportService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFilesService, FilesService>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

app.Run();
```

Proxy.conf.js...

```
   const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:19229';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api/*"
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Another api controller that works fine...

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public User ModifyUser(AzureUser user)
    {
        return _userService.ModifyUser(user);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return _userService.GetUsers();
    }
}
```

But no matter what I do...

https://localhost:44427/api/files/123 returns a 404.

https://localhost:44427/api/files/DownloadFile/test.csv returns a 404.

Other API controller methods work, so the port is correct.

The other api controllers only have one GET though, whenever I try to add multiple GETs using attribute routing, they both just end of returning a 404.

Comment: can you try swapping the position of `app.MapControllers();
app.UseRouting();` lines? also can you share the routing if you have configured it?

Comment: I haven't used conventional routing I've used attribute routing, so the routing setup is just what's above in the controller as I thought you didn't need to map any routes in program.cs if you use attribute based routing?

Comment: Also try adding [Action] on your actions methods and see

Comment: @viveknuna tried swapping position of those app. statements in program.cs, no luck.

When you say add [Action] do you mean literally just change the top level route from  [Route("api/[controller]")] to  [Route("api/[controller]/[Action]")] and leave the method level routes as they are?

Comment: @viveknuna also updated my question with the proxy.conf.js not sure if this makes any difference or not to how the routes need to work.

Comment: may be related to case. Can you try https://localhost:44427/api/Files/123

Comment: @SmartCoder that still returns a 404.

Comment: Very odd if I amend GetFiles to just be HTTPGet instead of HTTPGet("{id}") it works. But as soon as I try to specify {id} it returns a 404.

Comment: But ideally I need these two routes on a method level, read through the docs and what I'm doing seems to be correct for attribute routing

Comment: Try exit from Visual Studio, delete `bin` and `obj`, clean browser cache and try again, because your code works for me, but without `Proxy.conf...`

Comment: @Victor tried that still no luck, should mention I'm not using it in the browser yet, just trying to test it by hitting it through postman first.

Comment: I use the proxy.conf as it's an angular application, so I used the template in VS 2022 for an angular .net core app, it auto generated that proxy.conf for me to use when debugging locally.

Comment: Are there other methods in the same controller that work fine?

Comment: @OJRaqueño no none of them work, but I have another controller, that just has a post and a get, they work fine. But in that controller I don't have routes on a method level just the controller level route [Route("api/[controller]")]. Now wondering if the proxy.conf is somehow messing with it.

Comment: Updated my question with code for the controller that works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this.

It was the proxy.conf.js.

I had to change "/api/*" to "/api/**" in the context array, ** seems to be a catch all.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should inherit the class `ControllerBase`.

Instead of this:

```
public class FilesController
```

Try this:

```
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: Indeed did miss that, added it, unfortunately both routes still 404.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging?

Does a file with the ID 123 or name test.csv actually exist?

https://localhost:44427/api/files/123

https://localhost:44427/api/files/DownloadFile/test.csv

If not then then the service methods may return null which will lead to a 404 by default.

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging. If I change [HttpGet("{id}")] to [HttpGet] and pass id 123, then it hits the breakpoint in the controller and returns files from GetFiles. But as soon as I add "{id}" it returns a 404.